# C# - Changes in DataBound TextFields does not change the datarow state to Modified, stays Unchanged - Windows Form

Tags: c#, data-binding, visual-studio-2015, ado.net

I am having an issue updating the datasource with dataAdapter as it find no modified dataRows in the DataTable. I have a simple form with two TextFields and a Button. The textfields are dataBound to a BindingSource, loading data into the textfields work as normal, when i modify the textfield (say i change the firstname to something else) the datarow rowstate remains Unchanged. I have done alot of search online but couldnt find a solution. this is the code:

Below is how data is loaded into the textfields.

```
private void frmReceiveOrders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (SqlConnection conn = DBManager.getOpenConnection()) {

            adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT firstname, lastname from test", conn);
            adp.Fill(dtNames);
            adp.Dispose();

            b.DataSource = dtNames;

            txtFirst.DataBindings.Add("Text", b, "firstname");
            txtLast.DataBindings.Add("Text", b, "lastname");

        }
}
```

Below is how i save to the datasource but rw always returns 0 rows.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (SqlConnection conn = DBManager.getOpenConnection()) {
            SqlCommandBuilder bld = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);
            int rw = adp.Update(dtNames);
            MessageBox.Show("rows affected " + rw.ToString());
        }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is frmReceiveOrders_Load in if(!page.isPostBack)? if you call every time the page loads, then changed values wont appear

Comment: What John says. That seems to be asp.net. So databinding is not two-way. That means changed values are not automatically written back to the datasource. You should try to receive the changed values from the control you are binding your datatable to.

Comment: Most likely you need to include the PK field (Id or something) in your `dtNames`

Comment: this is a WindowsForm application.

Comment: i have a more complex project which contained primary key and had the same result, thats why i created a smaller demo to make it easy.